# Prove $x_n$ converges to $a$ iff every subsequence of $x_n$ also converges to $a$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Prove $x_n$ converges to $a$ iff every subsequence of $x_n$ also converges to $a$. Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb R$.

**Definitions available:**

**(1)** A sequence of real numbers $\{x_n\}$ is said to converge to a real number $a\in \mathbb R$ if and only if for $\quad$ every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there is an $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $n\ge N \to |x_n-a|\lt \epsilon$.

**(2)** By a subsequence of a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$, we mean a sequence of the form $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k \in \mathbb N}$, where $\quad$ each $n_k\in \mathbb N$ and $n_1\lt n_2\lt \cdots$.

**(3)** If $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converges to $a$ and $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k \in \mathbb N}$ is any subsequence of $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ then $x_{n_k}$ converges $\quad$ to $a$ as $k\to \infty$.

**My attempt:**

Let $x_n$ converge to $a$ and $\{x_{n_k}\}$ be a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ where $n_k\in \mathbb N$. Since we know for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\ge N \to |x_n-a|\lt \epsilon$, if we minimize $b$ such that $n_b\ge N$ , then $|x_n-a|\lt \epsilon$ for any $k\ge b$. Therefore, $\{x_{n_k}\}$ converges to $a$.

Does this work for the first direction? For the second direction, is it acceptable to say that if every subsequence converges to $a$, it is trivial that $\{x_n\}$ converges to $a$, because $\{x_n\}$ is a subsequence of itself?

Comment: Does not (3) prove the first direction?

Comment: For the second direction, i'll state it informally but, you'll know how to write it in epsilon-delta form afterwards. If the main sequence does not converge to a than that epsilon-delta inequality is not satisfied(write it down!). Immediately, it follows that you have at least 2 infinite groups of numbers in the sequence clumped up in two different intervals.(Here you can see a contradiction.)

Comment: Your argument for the second direction is absolutely correct. $(x_n)$ is a perfectly respectable subsequence of itself.

Comment: Informally, when you say a sequence converges to a number, you are saying that except for some numbers in the sequence(finite number of numbers) all other lye in any desired interval(as small as you like) centered at the number the sequence converges.

Comment: @Bungo The theorem is also true if you would leave that out.

Comment: @shooting-squirrel: Sure, but in that case I can just choose another trivial subsequence such as $y_n = x_{n+1}$. Where do you draw the line at which subsequences aren't proper enough? :-)

Comment: @Bungo A subsequence that misses at least one number from an infinite number of couples of numbers that are consecutive(in the initial sequence) and are from the initial sequence. The theorem would still be true and you could not say that it is trivially true. Or even more simple, if all subsequences that lack an infinite number of numbers from the initial sequence converge, the theorem would still be true.

Comment: @Bungo It's pretty cool if you draw parallels with reality.

Comment: @Bungo But then it would be pretty trivially as well, because you could take the 2 subsequences formed by the numbers with odd and even indices respectively.

Comment: @shooting-squirrel: OK, I agree that you can prove stronger statements than the one in the OP. But I think it would mislead Vincent to say that his argument for the second direction is incorrect in any way, for the theorem stated here.

Comment: This implication $\Rightarrow$ is explained above and the $\Leftarrow$ is trivial. A more interesting statement to prove (at least the $\Leftarrow$ part) is: a sequence is convergent to $a$ if and only if every subsequence of that sequence has itself a subsequence convergent to $a$. Note that we need to specify the limit, since all bounded sequence have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Another way to say that the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in N}$ converges to $x$ is that whenever $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$, the set $\{n \in N : x_n\not \in V\}$ is finite. This often simplifies things.